# Using let hello = `My age is ${age}` but updating age is not updating the age in this command

Tags: javascript, constants, let

I wanted to set the greeting so I wouldn't have to type it out in full anymore.

So I did:

```
let hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`
```

So to have me greet, I would just type:

```
console.log(hello);
```

However, later I updated the age

```
++age;
```

But when I did that, and I greeted myself  again

```
console.log(hello);
```

The "age" that is inside of that "hello" didn't show as updated.

For example,

```
let age = 20;
let name = "John";
let hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`
console.log(hello);
```

...The output is: My name is John and I am 20 years old.

Then I updated the age

```
++age;
console.log(hello);
```

...But the output is still: My name is John and I am 20 years old.

.
.

Originally I had

```
const hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`
```

But changing "const" to "let" didn't seem to make a difference.

I also tried

```
age++;
```

instead of

```
++age;
```

to see if I was remembering that command incorrectly but neither seem to make a difference.

Comment: By the way, `age++` and `++age` is the same if you look at it as a command. But as an expression, `age++` returns the old value (and then increments as a side-effect) and `++age` _first_ increments and then returns the new value. Check `console.log(age++)` vs `console.log(++age)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your `hello` assignment ran, `hello` has the static value of e.g. `My name is John and I am 20 years old`. Changing `age` won't have any effect on `hello`, unless you do the assingment again:

```js
let age = 20
let name = "John"
let hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`
console.log(hello)

age++
hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old` // << THIS
console.log(hello)
```

However, this is of course duplicate code which is never a good thing. So, you could use a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Function) instead:

```js
const getHello = (age, name) => `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`

let age = 20
let name = "John"
console.log(getHello(age, name))

age++
console.log(getHello(age, name))
```

Here, the variables are given as arguments. If you need it only in one place and you want to directly read from the local variables, you can also [close over them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), like this:

```js
let age = 20
let name = "John"

const getHello = () => `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`

console.log(getHello())

age++
console.log(getHello())
```

Yet another way would be to keep using `hello` as local variable, but have a function that updates it, so you still need to remember updating it but it takes away the duplicate code of the actual string interpolation:

```js
let age = 20
let name = "John"
let hello

const updateHello = () => {
  hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`
}

updateHello()
console.log(hello)

age++
updateHello()
console.log(hello)
```

A less explicit way that appears more like an automatically updating variable would be using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). You can't define a local variable as getter though, but you can do it inside a class for example (or an object in general):

```js
class Test {
  constructor (age, name) {
    this.age = age
    this.name = name
  }

  get hello () {
    return `My name is ${this.name} and I am ${this.age} years old`
  }
}

const test = new Test(20, "John")
console.log(test.hello)

test.age++
console.log(test.hello)
```

---

**Side note**: The frontend framework [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) has [reactive declarations](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations) which work more in the way that you imagined here, using the `$:` prefix.

```html
<script>
  let name = "John"
  let age = 20
  $: hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`

  function handleClick() {
    age += 1
  }
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={name}><br>
<input type="number" bind:value={age}>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
  Increase age
</button>

<p>{hello}</p>
```

[See live example](https://svelte.dev/repl/f0b63637ddbb49caa7709b6993cabd2d?version=3.23.2)

Comment: Ahhh this was an amazing explanation. I'm going to play around with the different options but its all really good to know. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
const hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`
```

`name` and `age` are "merged" with the string, so it is not stored as variable inside a string but rather as one whole string. So you would have to do something like this, you could put in and a function if you're going to generate alot of these strings:

```
let age = 20;
let name = "John";
let hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`
console.log(hello);
age++;
hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`
console.log(hello);
```

Comment: Ahhh so basically my shortcut is not possible this way.. haha. I guess I can retype the updated hello and its not too much.

Answer (score 0):

Assign hello again.

```js
let age = 20;
let name = "John";
let hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`
console.log(hello);
++age;
hello = `My name is ${name} and I am ${age} years old`
console.log(hello);
```

Answer (score 0):

think of it like this :

```
let a = 2;
let b = 3;
let sum = a + b;
console.log(sum); //writes 5 to the console

a++;
console.log(sum); //still writes 5 to the console
```